# Rails Dynamic Edit Path vs. Static Edit Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I'm working on a Rails project while going through *Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial*. I think I have a basic grasp of everything, but I'm having a hard time understanding why he sets the edit path to **"users/edit/:id" vs just "user/edit"**.

Doesn't it make more sense to have a static edit link for everyone rather than looking up the user based on the :id? After all, the current user will already be signed in so why refer to the user being edited with the :id when it could just edit the current user?

Maybe I'm missing an obvious benefit, but I'd love to hear some best practices regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in rails a resource is an editable entity , for instance you can have product as a resource and edit the product specification of it as you want. Now , the routing scheme you mentioned **users/4/edit** makes the task of finding resource id for such resources easier .In your case user id as it can be directly picked from url by rails (like if route users/:id/edit then :id will have the user id)

Its not necessary to follow that style of routing , as in case you mentioned user/edit makes much more sense and it is much more convenient . But then the challenge lies as to how will you determine the user id of current user? you may use session variable or something for this or as per your rails app design.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because user can edit just his own profile. Edit another user's profiles is not allowed. (for example he can follow to `users/3/edit` `users/4/edit`, but will not get any access to edit them. Thus we have restricted those pathes with just its own `users/edit`

Comment: Exactly, but why even use the numbers if the user is only allowed to edit their own profile?

Comment: Its CRUD convention for naming in rails by default `:resources_name/:id/:action` and we want to overrride it for example for user or users